# Reactive-Forms. Resetting validation errors while leaving values in place

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'd like to reset a specific field upon every change in the form.

This is what I wish to achieve:

```
  this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    const field = this.formGroup.get('field')
    for (const item in field.errors)  field.setErrors({ item: null })
  })
```

But it doesn't seem the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: could you send a piece of code showing the context please? I think I understand what you mean but not sure about it

Comment: Be sure you write the code this.formGrou.valueChanges.. **after** you create the form

Comment: To let people know what they did wrong it is useful to leave a comment explaining the  reason for their down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with what you have, I'd added one thing.

```js
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  const field = this.formGroup.get('field')
  for (const item in field.errors) field.setErrors({
    item: null
  })
})
```

After that loop, add:

```js
this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
```

[AbstractControl - updateValueAndValidity](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity)

Comment: field.updateValueAndValidity() did the job, as opposed to this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();